# Text Extraction from HTML Data

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, text-extraction

I have have a problem with extracting information from messy HTML data.  Basically what I want to do is extract only the actual displayed words from a given piece of HTML code.  Here is an example of the raw HTML data I am given

```
<p>I have an app which send mail to my defined mail address "myemail@own.com". For this i create my own Custom Email View Which contains check boxes message body and other options. Now i want that when send button is pressed my app should not go to gmail view or other email client view it directly submit the data</p>

<p>String recepientEmail = "myemail@own.comm"; </p>

<p>// either set to destination email or leave empty</p>

<pre><code>    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);

    intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:" + recepientEmail));

    startActivity(intent);
</code></pre>

<p>but on submit it opens gmail or chooser email client view but i dont want to show gmail view</p>
```

and I want to transform it into this

```
I have an app which send mail to my defined mail address "myemail@own.com". For this i create my own Custom Email View Which contains check boxes message body and other options. Now i want that when send button is pressed my app should not go to gmail view or other email client view it directly submit the data String recepientEmail = "myemail@own.comm"; // either set to destination email or leave empty but on submit it opens gmail or chooser email client view but i dont want to show gmail view
```

So basically just retrieve everything within each of the `<p>` tags and concatenate them together.  I am using python so I am thinking BeautifulSoup is probably the best way to do this, however I can't seem to figure out how to do this.  I am also want to repeat this over several such examples (actually millions), but each example should have at least one `<p>` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[html2text](http://www.aaronsw.com/2002/html2text/) is a Python script that converts a page of HTML into clean, easy-to-read plain ASCII text. Better yet, that ASCII also happens to be valid Markdown (a text-to-HTML format).

```
<span id="midArticle_1"></span><p>Here is the First Paragraph.</p><span id="midArticle_2"></span><p>Here is the second Paragraph.</p><span id="midArticle_3"></span><p>Paragraph Three."</p>

print html.parse(url).xpath('//p/text()')
```

**OUTPUT**

> ['Here is the First Paragraph.', 'Here is the second Paragraph.',
>   'Paragraph Three."']

Comment: Cool find! So this removes everything in all tags except <p> tags?

Comment: I wanted the output to be just one big string.  So I guess I could just join the output that you provided.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what the "html" object is.  Are you using html2text in this example?

Answer (score 2):

One way using `BeautifulSoup` module to extract all text from `<p>` tags.

Content of `script.py`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys 

soup = BeautifulSoup(open(sys.argv[1], 'r'), 'html')

print(' '.join(map(lambda e: e.string, soup.find_all('p'))))
```

Run it like:

```
python3 script.py infile
```

That yields:

```
I have an app which send mail to my defined mail address "myemail@own.com". For this i create my own Custom Email View Which contains check boxes message body and other options. Now i want that when send button is pressed my app should not go to gmail view or other email client view it directly submit the data String recepientEmail = "myemail@own.comm";  // either set to destination email or leave empty but on submit it opens gmail or chooser email client view but i dont want to show gmail view
```

Comment: Thanks.  Can anyone tell me which of these two solutions is the fastest?  I have a lot of examples to run through.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry.  For some examples I am getting the error "sequence item 1: expected string or Unicode, NoneType found" for the join line.  Could you tell me how to get around this?

Answer (score 1):

I recently started playing around with Beautiful Soup.
I found this line of code that was extremely helpful. I will throw in my entire example in to show you.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("your url")

html_text = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text)

clean_html = ''.join(soup.findAll(text=True))

print(clean_html)
```

Hopefully this works for you/answers your question